# Как оформить несогласованное приложени?

Tags: приложение

Нужно ли ставить тире после названия сказки?

*Русская сказка «Финист – ясный сокол» (?) о девушке, которая спасает возлюбленного от чар колдуньи и себя от злых сестёр.*

Меня интересует пунктуация именно при таком порядке слова. Буду рада ответу )).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это предложение, то **тире** нужно поставить, а иначе это выглядит как номинативное **словосочетание**.  С другой стороны, и при постановке тире такой вариант оформления для структуры этого предложения **не очень подходит** (в том числе из-за тире в **названии**). Поэтому я бы написала так:

*Русская сказка «Финист – ясный сокол» **повествует** о девушке, которая спасает возлюбленного от чар колдуньи, а также себя от злых сестёр.*

В то же время окончательный выбор делается с учетом **контекста**.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!